# Groupby behavior on set_index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
   year state           0
0  2010    AK   24.524096
1  2010    AL  186.981422
2  2010    AR   45.076047
3  2010    AZ   91.604977
4  2010    CA -109.784572
[...]
```

I want to set the index in the order *state>year* and have the values grouped in the same order. When i do `ratio.set_index(['state', 'year']).head(3)` i get

```
                     0
state year            
AK    2010   24.524096
AL    2010  186.981422
AR    2010   45.076047
```

instead of

```
            0
state year   
AK    2010  1
      2011  1
      2012  1
      2013  1
      2014  1
      2015  1
      2016  1
      2017  1
      2018  1
AL    2010  1
```

which I achieve doing `ratio.groupby(['state', 'year']).count().head(10)` but this do not gives the values I want. I don't know why setting the index in order is not grouping the values or if this is the intended behaviour. Is there anyway I can get the values grouped in that hierarchical order? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the MultiIndex, or do you just want the two columns sorted by state then year?

Comment: In the `set_index()` part you are showing the values whereas in the `groupby` you are aggregating by the `count`. Also, what is your desired output? What are you trying to achieve, the top 3 years per state per what? (count? mean? max value?)

Comment: The reason you might be attracted to groupby is because by default it **sorts** the grouping keys, in addition to putting them in the index. But you don't actually need to aggregate here so groupby is incorrect. Instead `ratio.set_index(['state', 'year']).sort_index()`, or `ratio.sort_values(['state', 'year'])` if the MultiIndex is unnecessary

Comment: The values I want in the groupingby is the column with numerical values whose name is 0

Comment: @ALollZ I think that's it. I want them by index because I will bar plot them by state and in each state plot the corresponding year values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `ratio.set_index(['state', 'year']).sort_index()` gives the correct output. Thanks to @ALollz.